# django different serializer for GET and PUT - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use get_serializer_class() and I'm getting error messages.  Here's my view -

```
class CalendarDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            serializer_class = CalendarGETSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer_class = CalendarPUTSerializer
        return serializer_class

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        evntname = self.request.GET.get('name')
        queryset = Evntmst.objects.filter(evntmst_name=evntname)
        serializer = get_serializer_class(queryset)
        if queryset:
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            raise Http404

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = get_serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

And here's my urls.py -

```
url(r'^deploy/calendartest/$', CalendarDetail.as_view(), name='CalendarDetail'),
```

As soon as I try to hit the URL I get the following error message -

```
    class CalendarDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[14/Sep/2014 20:08:16] "GET /deploy/calendartest/?name=cal_daily HTTP/1.1" 500 5
9
```

I'm guessing it's something internal to the class that I'm calling properly and the syntax error is not necessarily true?
What I don't get is that I've designed the class as I would all my other classes that work, and I have a separate view doing a simple get with one serializer that returns that URL as a 200 NOT a 500.

Comment: Sometimes, when you get a syntax error, the problem is on the line above it. Is there anything directly above the class definition that looks broken?

Comment: nope I have a comment line before the class line `## TEST CLASS VIEW`

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first line of code that isn't a comment/blank line/things the interpreter will ignore.

Comment: Woohoo!  You are correct I went another line up I inadvertently deleted a closing bracket on the previous line of code.  We're good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had a few issues.  One was in the previous view I inadvertently removed a closing bracked on the previous line to the view I posted.

Second, get_serializer_class requires ()(queryset) to call the instance properly.

I'm trying to use get_serializer_class() and I'm getting error messages. Here's my view -

class CalendarDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        serializer_class = CalendarGETSerializer
    elif self.request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer_class = CalendarPUTSerializer
    return serializer_class

def get(self, request, format=None):
    evntname = self.request.GET.get('name')
    queryset = Evntmst.objects.filter(evntmst_name=evntname)
    serializer = get_serializer_class()(queryset)
    if queryset:
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        raise Http404
```